# How can I check one Interface is extend another Interface in java

Tags: java

Interface1 extends Interface2

var = Interface1 // getting name of Interface1 in var.
if(Interface1 extends Interface2 ) // how can be test this condition.

Comment: `Interface2.class.isAssignableFrom(Interface1.class)`

Comment: Name of interface? You'll need to get the class of the interface.

Comment: Such things are not expected to change. So why do you want to test something that is already known at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you have `.class` references to the interfaces, you can use [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-).

```
if (Interface2.class.isAssignableFrom(Interface1.class)) {
    // Interface1 is a subtype of Interface2
}
```